# Android: Cannot share image from SD card

Tags: android, image, file, uri

I try to share a picture from my SD card.

Class MainActivity.java

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

String fileName = "/cats.jpg";

File file = new File(baseDir + fileName);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(shareIntent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send Picture"));
```

I add to my Manifest.xml:

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

The image "cats" is in 
      `MySmartphone\Card\DCIM\cats.jpg`

When I start my App, I can choose an application to share my picture. But when I open one, it cannot send or open the image.I got often a toast "not supported" or "error to share picture". I think my uri or file is wrong, but I cannot find my mistake. I have no problem to send text.

My uri: 
    `file:///data/user/0/com.example.jana.showpicture/files/cats.jpg`

My file:  `/storage/emulated/0/cats.jpg`

Comment: `mage "cats" is in  MySmartphone\Card\DCIM\cats.jpg` ?? That is a non existing path. You as a programmer should know better. Try to find the real file path for your image.

Comment: `My uri:   file:///data/user/0/com.example.jana.showpicture/files/cats.jpg` Where did you get that uri from? That path would be internal private memory. You can reach it with getFilesDir().

Comment: `My file:  /storage/emulated/0/cats.jpg `. That path has nothing to do with your uri as it comes from getExternalStorageDirectory(). Your post is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are building for Android API 24 and above. Since API 24 a new kind of security was added. See:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm

You now need to do a bit more, add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.jana.showpicture.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

`/res/xml/provider_paths.xml`:

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And Java:

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,"com.example.jana.showpicture.provider",
                    file);
 shareIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not work.  
Now my file has the reference:    `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/cats.jpg `  
  My uri looks like:  `Content://com.example.jana.sharepicture.fileprovider/external_files/DCIM/cats.jpg ` 
  The App works as described above. If I want to share my Image as  eMail attachment, 
I got an error in logcat:   `W/System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/cats,jpg`